# Zend Gmail Oauth: How to get authenticated user profile?

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, gmail

I am using Zend Gmail Oauth 1.0 for implementing login with Gmail feature.
After successful authentication, how can I get authenticated user's profile, specifically user's unique gmail id? Here is the code:

```
$THREE_LEGGED_SCOPES = array('https://mail.google.com/', 
    'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds');

$options = array(
        'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
        'version' => '1.0',
        'consumerKey' => $THREE_LEGGED_CONSUMER_KEY,
        'consumerSecret' => $THREE_LEGGED_CONSUMER_SECRET_HMAC,
        'callbackUrl' => getCurrentUrl(),
        'requestTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
        'userAuthorizationUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
        'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'
    );

    if ($THREE_LEGGED_SIGNATURE_METHOD == 'RSA-SHA1') {
        $options['signatureMethod'] = 'RSA-SHA1';
        $options['consumerSecret'] = new Zend_Crypt_Rsa_Key_Private(
            file_get_contents(realpath($THREE_LEGGED_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY)));
    } else {
        $options['signatureMethod'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
        $options['consumerSecret'] = $THREE_LEGGED_CONSUMER_SECRET_HMAC;
    }

    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($options);

    /**
     * When using HMAC-SHA1, you need to persist the request token in some way.
     * This is because you'll need the request token's token secret when upgrading
     * to an access token later on. The example below saves the token object 
     * as a session variable.
     */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'])) {
      if (!isset($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {
        // Get Request Token and redirect to Google
        $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getRequestToken(array('scope' => implode(' ', $THREE_LEGGED_SCOPES))));
        $consumer->redirect();
      } else {
        // Have Request Token already, Get Access Token
        $_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])));
        header('Location: ' . getCurrentUrl(false));
        exit;
      } 
    } else {
      // Retrieve mail using Access Token
      $accessToken = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

near as I can tell you can't. 
Gmail doesn't have an api just a read only [feed](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed).
However if you want that feed the scope url is:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/
```

There are some api's for working with gmail accounts in the context of [Google Apps](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/libraries_and_samples.html).